# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /xxx/xxx/jenkins-slave/workspace/

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

Below code is working when i run in local

```
    String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filepath);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

but,when i run the same scripts with above code in jenkins it is throwing below error, so please help me what might be the issue
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /xxx/xxx/jenkins-slave/workspace/

More info on project:
I'am using maven project and executing the scripts through testng.xml using below command in both local and in jenkins
mvn -DReportDB=false -DlogFilename=finalTest -DlogDirectory=D:\Logs compile failsafe:integration-test -DsuiteXmlFile=testngScreensSanity.xml

Comment: I' am new to jenkins, so not sure what changes to do in jenkins to proceed with my testing

Comment: may be the machine you are running jenkins on, might not have permission to execute chromedriver.exe.